# PHP Post to mysql with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So i'm trying to execute a Insert Statement using PHP, but when i call the part of the code that should do it, nothing happends...

Already checked it up to see what's going wrong, but could't find out.

Here's the JavaScript function that calls the PHP code.

```
function comparaSenhas(){
    var pass = document.getElementById("pwd1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("pwd2").value;
    if(pass !== pass2){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function postData(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "../mysql.php";
    var fstnm = document.getElementById("fn").value;
    var lstnm = document.getElementById("ln").value;
    var dtnasc = document.getElementById("dn").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("em").value;
    var senha = document.getElementById("pwd1").value;
    var vars = "fname="+fstnm+"&lname="+lstnm+"&dt_nasc="+dtnasc+"&email="+email+"&senha="+senha;

    if(comparaSenhas()){

        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                alert(return_data);
            }
        }

        hr.send(vars);

    }

}
```

And here's the PHP code that i'm using.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "godienski";
        $dbname = "web";

        //create connection
         $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        if($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into usuarios(first_name, last_name, data_nascimento, email, senha) values (?,?,?,?,?);");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$firstname,$lastname,$dtnascimento,$mail,$password);

        $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
        $dtnascimento = $_POST['dt_nasc'];
        $mail = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['senha'];
        $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is _easily done_ using jQuery, consider using it.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the console? Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: More details please. Is the php code executed? Is there any error in error_log?

Comment: You're not checking for errors in your AJAX call or in the calls to MySQL. If something goes wrong you have no way to know.

Comment: One problem I can see right off is that your variables are declared after they are being used. So move the declerations up before you start preparing the SQL statement.